# How configure bash environment with rbenv?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rbenv

I'm actually working to maintain a Ruby application on a server which is not up to date (Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS). RVM is installed globaly, i've tried to obtain a recent ruby version locally, in my home directory, without any success. And now I'm trying with rbenv.

I've just installed Ruby 2.3.1 with rbenv & ruby-build (as rbenv plugins).
The install worked perfectly, but not the usage.

The installation (the easy part) :

```
$ rbenv install 2.3.1
Downloading ruby-2.3.1.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.3/ruby-2.3.1.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.3.1...
Installed ruby-2.3.1 to /home/atlantic/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1
```

I've updated the .bash_profile like they said :

```
$ cat .bash_profile 
# include .bashrc if it exists
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

But when I want to check the environnement lot of environnement parameters use global path (like GEM PATHS, EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY, INSTALLATION DIRECTORY, ...) :

```
$ gem env 
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.5.1
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.3.1 (2016-04-26 patchlevel 112) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/atlantic/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/atlantic/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/atlantic/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /home/atlantic/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/atlantic/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin
     - /home/atlantic/.rbenv/libexec
     - /home/atlantic/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin
     - /home/atlantic/.rbenv/shims
     - /home/atlantic/.rbenv/bin
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin
     - /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin
     - /usr/local/rvm/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
```

When I look the env, there lot of env variables who target the global ruby installation. I do not know from where theses variables we're set but that's not the value I want for them :

```
$ env |grep -i ruby
GEM_HOME=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247
IRBRC=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/.irbrc
MY_RUBY_HOME=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247
PATH=/home/atlantic/.rbenv/shims:/home/atlantic/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
GEM_PATH=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global
RUBY_VERSION=ruby-2.0.0-p247
```

The rbenv ruby installation never appear on theses variables.
Do I have a command (like a rbenv init-env-variables) to lauch to configure correctly my ruby env ?

Thanks for your support,
David

Comment: Did you remember to `source ~/.bash_profile `? Also check your .bashrc and see if RVM added anything. All of your gem paths are still pointed towards the RVM installation.

Comment: I've found /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh which define all theses variables. Do I unset all variables before execute rbenv init ? Any advice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've manually update the file .bash_profile to unset all variables environnements which in use with rvm and now it works perfectly :

```
$ cat /home/atlantic/.bash_profile 
# include .bashrc if it exists
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

unset rvm_bin_path
unset GEM_HOME
unset IRBRC
unset MY_RUBY_HOME
unset rvm_path
unset rvm_prefix
unset rvm_version
unset GEM_PATH
unset RUBY_VERSION


export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

The result :

```
$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.5.1
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.3.1 (2016-04-26 patchlevel 112) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/atlantic/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/atlantic/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/atlantic/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/atlantic/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/atlantic/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /home/atlantic/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/atlantic/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
     - /home/atlantic/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/atlantic/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin
     - /home/atlantic/.rbenv/libexec
     - /home/atlantic/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin
     - /home/atlantic/.rbenv/shims
     - /home/atlantic/.rbenv/bin
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin
     - /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin
     - /usr/local/rvm/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
```

Thanks for your suggestions and your help.
David.

Answer (score 0):

Run `rvm implode --force`

This will remove the rvm/ directory and all the rubies built within it.

Run `gem uninstall rvm`

Check `.bashrc`, `.profile` and `.bash_profile` and remove any references to RVM. Should look something like this

`[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function`

Remove RVM from the following locations

```
rm -rf /usr/local/rvm
sudo rm /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
sudo rm /etc/rvmrc
```

Remove these lines from `/etc/profile` if they exist

```
source /etc/profile.d/sm.sh
source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
```

Reload your terminal with `source` and restart the rbenv install process.

Comment: I'm totally agree with you but I do not have root/sudo access on this server.